# linking to admin from the main site - session parameter

Tags: sessions, admin

I want to provide admin links from the main site for clients, however within the admin URL there is the session parameter.

Is there a way to output the admin url path that includes the dynamic session parameter? Alternatively i can switch the session ID off in security settings but thats a second preference.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

It is possible, but the mechanism for generating session IDs changed for EE 2.6, so if you want to retain compatibility with 2.5 and under (as I did) you need to add in a quick `version_compare` check.

Here's the snippet that I'm using with [Missing Link](http://www.vayadesign.net/software/missing-link).

```
$sess_type = $this->EE->config->item('admin_session_type');
$session_id = ($sess_type == 'c') ? '0' : $this->userdata['session_id'];

if (version_compare(APP_VER, '2.6.0', '>=') AND $sess_type == 'cs')
{
 $session_id = $this->userdata['fingerprint'];
}
```

That should give you an accurate `$session_id` no matter which EE version or session type is in use.

I'd strongly recommend creating a plugin for this, if you haven't already, as PHP in templates is a [Bad Idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13096532/is-there-ever-a-good-reason-to-use-php-inside-expressionengine-templates).

Comment: $this->userdata has to point to $this->EE->session->userdata (or the newer ee() funtion )

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no native way to output the admin URL path with a dynamic session preset. You will have to have cookies turned on and include `S=0&` right after the `?` in URL.

Comment: With cp-security set to both cookies and session-id, when you leave out S=value or when you set S=0 in the url, you get thrown back to the login page :-(